# 2 Virtual Hosts on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, virtual, host

Hi to everyone I have two different sites and I want to two different host:
movie.local
music.local

These are my files:

```
#
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
127.0.0.1   movie.local
127.0.0.1   music.local
```

And

```
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName movie.local

    ServerAlias www.movie.local

    DocumentRoot "/Users/Me/Sites/movie"

    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/site-error_log"

    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/site-access_log" common

    ServerAdmin neilgee@coolestguidesontheplanet.com

        <Directory "/Users/Me/Sites/movie">

            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

            AllowOverride All

            Order allow,deny

            Allow from all

        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

         ServerName music.local

        ServerAlias www.music.local
        DocumentRoot "/Users/Me/Sites/music"

    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/site-error_log"

   CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/site-access_log" common

    ServerAdmin neilgee@coolestguidesontheplanet.com

        <Directory "/Users/Me/Sites/music">

            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

            AllowOverride All

            Order allow,deny

            Allow from all

        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But now if I go to movie.local that's ok, but if i go to music.local my browser will load the content of movie.local, why?

Comment: "if i go to music.local my browser will load the content of music.local, why?" Isn't this what you want? Or did you state that incorrectly? Anyway, always remember to restart httpd after you edit any config files.

Comment: Sorry I've edited, yes I did it

Comment: [The argument to the <VirtualHost> directive must match a defined NameVirtualHost directive.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) You don't appear to have defined `NameVirtualHost *:80`.

Comment: If you do this a lot you might want to use [Localghost](http://scotchi.net/localghost/) to make editing that file easier. You can also use [xip.io](http://xip.io/) to do the mapping, for example: `movies.127.0.0.1.xip.io` will resolve to `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

if i go to music.local my browser will load the content of movie.local, why?
You can create a subdomain on your localhost like this.

First create a virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName music.localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Me/Sites/music"
 <Directory "C:/Users/Me/Sites/music">
/....../
/....../
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

And in your hosts file add this line:
127.0.0.1      music.localhost
```